# Array of functions for getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to recreate a solution similar to this:
http://bit.ly/1kD64dR

I need a DRY solution as I am going to be recreating this for 20+ elements:

I have tried creating an array of ids, and then calling a single function on each array but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the logic. I am restarting from the ground up...

What I want to accomplish is to show a series of images (for now i'm using text)... Each image will have a function applied to the onClick event, and then the new div that is shown will also have a click event applied to it.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZ7PY/5/)

The actual excerpt from the code to be used showing each `li` element's contents:

```
...
<li>
  <a href="#" onClick="show13()">
    <img src="../images/rtw3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <div id="img3">
    <a href="#" onClick="hide13()">
      <img src=".../images/block.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
...
```

Everything *Works* in the demo above...I just want to streamline and simplify the code.
Here is the WET example:

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show1()">Click me</a>
    <div id="d1" class="hide">
        <a href="#" onclick="hide1()">Shown!</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show2()">Click me</a>
    <div id="d2" class="hide">
        <a href="#" onclick="hide2()">Shown!</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show3()">Click me</a>
    <div id="d3" class="hide">
        <a href="#" onclick="hide3()">Shown!</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show4()">Click me</a>
    <div id="d4" class="hide">
        <a href="#" onclick="hide4()">Shown!</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function show1(){
document.getElementById("d1").className ='show';
}
function hide1(){
document.getElementById("d1").className ='hide';
}
function show2(){
document.getElementById("d2").className ='show';
}
function hide2(){
document.getElementById("d2").className ='hide';
}
function show3(){
document.getElementById("d3").className ='show';
}
function hide3(){
document.getElementById("d3").className ='hide';
}
function show4(){
document.getElementById("d4").className ='show';
}
function hide4(){
document.getElementById("d4").className ='hide';
}
```

Comment: your fiddle works, you just forgot to set jquery

Comment: @Pavlo Dratts! Thank you for the assit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of inline `onclick` listeners and use jQuery way to listen `onclick` for each `a` and [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) of sibling `div`

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e){
    $(this).next("div").toggleClass("show hide");
});
```

## Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/X5zqB/)

---

## Edited (to make "Shown" disappear by click on it)

Change each `li` as follows (add `parent` and `nest` classed to `a`):

```
<li><a href="#" class="parent">Click me</a>
    <div id="d1" class="hide">
        <a href="#" class="nest">Shown!</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

And script will be:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.parent", function(e){
    $(this).next("div").toggleClass("show hide");
});

$(document).on("click", "a.nest", function(e){
    $(this).parent("div").toggleClass("show hide");
});
```

## Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/X5zqB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should exploit the DOM. All nodes (aka tags) in a document, and any events generated on that tree, "know" where they are in the tree.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="show(this)">Click me</a>
                              ^^^^^---- 
    <div id="d3" class="hide">
        <a href="#" onclick="hide(this)">Shown!</a>
                                  ^^^^----
    </div>
</li>

function show(obj) {
   obj.nextSibling.style="display: block"; // <div> is adjacent to the <a> that got clicked
}

function hide(obj) {
   obj.parentNode.style = "display: none"; // get the <div> above the clicked <a>
}
```

The same show/hide calls can be used in EVERY one of your `<li>` tags, and the DOM tree itself will take care of making sure the right nodes are shown/hidden.

Comment: `nextSibling` also selects the `textNode`s, `nextElementSibling` (_doesn't work in IE8_) is more safe.

Comment: safer would be using jquery .next() and whatnot, and let it handle the cross-platform problems.

Comment: IE8 not working will not be a factor as the @animation in the css will already not work... < IE10 is not a factor.

Answer (score 0):

A little example using jQuery

```
   $("li > a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".hide").toggleClass("show hide")
   })

  $(".hide > a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("show hide")
  })
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/pZ7PY/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is not to use `onclick` handlers in `html` and jQuery at all and just use javascript `querySelectorAll`, [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

For example:
`querySelectorAll('div[id^="d"]')` selects all ids which start with 'd'

then combine it with `forEach` [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

and use

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    (hide or show elements)
});
```

Advantages: no jQuery (not rly an advantage :)), no javascript in html (not an advantage if you think about code readability).

Hope you will get some new ideas.